# how do i detect if an android progressbar is using a particular style

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-styles

how do i detect if an android progressbar is using a particular style? i know how to set it, either with xml or code, but how to detect the style being used at runtime? there is no getStyle or such methods. and no, using indeterminate or indeterminateOnly doesn't work, because there is indeterminate progress horizontal style.

- I can detect the width/height ratio, if it is more than 1, then it is horizontal, otherwise this is a circular spinning wheel. but how do I ensure that this is not just a weirdly stretched spinning wheel?

edit: this is assuming i will develop for android version jelly bean or more

Comment: You need to detect that inside your own code?

Comment: actually i need to be able to change drawables at runtime, i don't wanna set wrong drawable to wrong style. have i been attacking this wrong?

Comment: Well I guess you could 1. use the `ProgressBar` class and try to figure those cases one by one (`getProgress()`, `isIndeterminate()`) or 2. simply create a custom `MyProgressBar` class that would extend `ProgressBar`?

Comment: hmm you are right, i will investigate those options, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I used the initial proposal combined with comments:

```java
if (!pb.isIndeterminate()) {
    isCircular = determineCircular(pb.getProgressDrawable());
} else {
    isCircular = determineCircular(pb.getIndeterminateDrawable());
    if (!isCircular) {
        pb.startAnimation(pb.getAnimation());
    }
}
```

```java
protected boolean determineCircular(Drawable drawable) {
    int iw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int ih = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
    if (ih == 0) return false; // division by zero
    double rat = iw / ih;
    // anticipate for some weird paddings
    return 0.8 < rat && rat < 1.2;
}
```

I haven't tested with some weird manufacturer skins yet, but I think this will be enough for standard sane Android.